# Two Bloc Builders in one page (Screen)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

How to show two different bloc builder in one page by using flutter_bloc package.For example i have created a row,in that row there is two columns. Each column has a separate bloc builder. But when i do this the first column builder shows but in the second column builder shows red screen and the error is "A build function returned null".

Comment: this is because your stream builder has to return some `Widget`but your code returned `null` instead

Comment: @pskink any examples of two bloc builders in one page